# Call a SQL proc with Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, dapper

I've written the following method to call my proc and place the returned data into a dataset.

```
public class GetDataFromProc
{
    string constr;
    public DataSet CallProcToDataSet(string procName)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBase"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procName))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = con;


                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                }
            }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

What I'm wanting to do is make use of the Dapper NuGet package. Checking through the docs, I can see the example proc calling line is as follows:

```
var user = cnn.Query<User>("spGetUser", new { Id = 1 }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
```

However, I'm not sure what the best way to convert my method into the above example would be. Could someone with more experience of Dapper help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Declare a model, with a property/field for every column
// that you care about from your Result
public class YourModel {

    public int Id {get;set;}
    // Whatever other columns your result has...
}



public class GetDataFromProc
{
    string constr;
    public IEnumerable<YourModel> CallProcToDataSet(string procName)
    {
        constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBase"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            // If you expect only one row
            var result = cnn.Query<YourModel>(procName, new { anyParametersYouHave = theirValue }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();

            // If you expect more than one row and want a collection
            var results= cnn.Query<YourModel>(procName, new { anyParametersYouHave = theirValue }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

        }
    }
 }
```